# Visual studio 2013 dataset not showing up column name for dynamic query of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I'm using a dynamic query in stored procedure as a tableadapter while creating a dataset in visual studio 2013. The problem is Data Column is not showing up Parameters and field for SELECT operation. Please find the screenshot:
[image: no parameters]

I'm not sure if this dynamic statement will work in this case.. Anybody know any possible way to use this stored procedure as datasource in my report.
query in stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' +@TableName + 
' WHERE ClassName='+@OperationName+' AND (RunTime BETWEEN '+@Date1+' AND '+@Date2+')
AND TestCaseId = ISNULL('+@TestCaseId+', TestCaseId)
 AND TestRunResult = ISNULL('+@TestRunResult+',TestRunResult) 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

Comment: I'm new to stack.. so my reputation does not allow to upload the screen shot.. i know that's crazy.. but i can't help :|

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BcEWl.png

Comment: Unless there's something new in 2010 I don't know about, a dataset always has to return the same collection of fields.   If you are doing SELECT * from a dynamically chosen table, then the field collection could vary depending on the table, which would break your report.

Comment: Well, I've same schema across the tables. I know it's a terrible practice to pass the table as a parameter. But I really need that. It's VS 2013. So, come to my original problem. How could I create a dataset with this dynamic query of stored procedure, which I eventually use to populate the reportviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the schema doesn't change then you can try this:

Start your stored procedure with something like this pseudo-code so SSRS knows what columns to expect:

```
IF 1=0
  SELECT 
    CAST('SomeDummyData' AS Field1DataType) AS Field1Name
  , CAST('SomeDummyData' AS Field2DataType) AS Field2Name
  , ETC...
ELSE
  ...the rest of your stored procedure
```

If that's not enough, open your DataSet and hard-code the fields in the Fields tab.